# Frame's definition (/odom and /map)

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, mapping, frame

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I cannot understand the difference between the frame "/odom" and "/map".
I've already read here -> http://ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#map
however, I couldn't understand.
It seems like the same frame.
**Could you explain the difference?**

And one more thing.
When I published a transform from "/map" to "/base_link" and launched rviz,
"/map" was shown in a strange position(very far from base_link's origin).
If possible, I'd like to set the position and orientation to a Grid Marker's corner.
**How is the position defined?**

I don't need to mind it?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44584/frame%27s-definition-(/odom-and-/map)/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The /odom frame is the place where your robot is initialized, while the /map frame is the origin of your map. Those are usually NOT the same (except your robot is standing at the exact origin of your map when beeing initialized).

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-26**:
See REP 105 for the details: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html